# How do I use keysSortedByValue in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift3, nsdictionary

I have this code for getting top values in an nsdictionary and adding to an array of NSdictionaries. and it gives me an error after converting to swift 3.

```
self.array = (self.dict!).keysSortedByValue
                        (comparator: {
                            ($1 ).compare($0 )
                    })
```

I get an ambiguous reference error.  It seems to have a problem with the format of comparator but I'm not sure how to change it.. anyone know?

Comment: Whats the type of `self.array`?

Comment: sorry it's an array of nsdictionaries

Comment: I'm just updating this app to swift 3 and there's a lot more code attached to this and this is the last error that I'm getting so if I could get this working it would save me from rewriting a ton of stuff lol

Answer (score 0):

The compiler probably can't infer $0 and $1 because the function type is `(Any, Any)`, which can't use `compare`.  So you have to cast them to `String` (or whatever type you're using that conforms to `compare`) and then back out to `Any`

```
let dict: NSDictionary = ["3" : "Orange", "1" : "Apple", "2" : "Pear"]
let keys = dict.keysSortedByValue(comparator: { (key1: String, key2: String) in
    return key1.compare(key2)
} as! (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult)
print(keys)
```

If I'm using Swift I prefer Swift dictionaries.

```
let swiftDict = ["3" : "Orange", "1" : "Apple", "2" : "Pear"]
let swiftKeys = swiftDict.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

Comment: The first part isn't working but I'm trying to just use regular dictionary as it looks a lot simpler

Comment: How do I sort it by values?  That's what the original code did

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally ended up working.  I couldn't get it working with NSDictionary so took Frankie's advice and just used a normal Dictionary.  Then used this code to sort it then append it to an array.

```
self.dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary
let sorted = self.dict.flatMap({$0})?.sorted { $0.0.1 > $0.1.1 }
for (name, value) in sorted! {
     self.array.append(name)
}
```